# How do I gain reputation in SuperUser if my questions never get answered?

Tags: support, reputation

I am trying to become an active user in this community, but the question I have asked has become a tumbleweed, and I don't have enough reputation to upvote any answers to other questions.  Looking through the unanswered questions, there don't really appear to be anything that relates to my area of expertise, and I don't see a lot of point in adding additional answers to questions that have already been adaquately answered.

Help?

Comment: Give it more time. Keep looking for questions you can provide answers to, they are out there.

Comment: He's not going to see this, if he doesn't understand the migration @ChrisF Perhaps I should have commented before migrating

Comment: However, he does seem to have an SO account with a little bit of rep

Comment: @Ivo - He might follow the link though if he revisits his question.

Comment: I got the majority of my rep from helping other and answering questions - not asking them. What is your user ID and/or link to some questions? I will take a look and see if I can answer anything.

Comment: Some people ask really simple questions that are just a google search away.  While these questions aren't really appropriate (people should search for answers before asking them), they are a really easy way to get reputation and you may even learn a thing or two looking up the answers.

Answer (score 4):

Answering questions gets you far more reputation (10 per upvote + 15 for accepted answer, instead of just 5 per question upvote).

You should look for unanswered questions (questions with no upvoted answers) with tags you have expertise in.  You can further sort that by newest so that you can answer question right away.  For example if you are a windows-7 expert you could go here:

https://superuser.com/unanswered/tagged?tagnames=windows-7&tab=newest

Which is unanswered questions with the windows-7 tag and sorted by newest.

Answer (score 3):

You asked one question that unfortunately no one was able to answer at the time. If you edit  your question to add more info, then it will get back to the top of the list.

My advice, stick to it and try asking other questions if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

Persistence: Everyone has something to offer - answer other users questions.  You'll gain rep from up-votes by other readers rewarding you for teaching them something new as well as from acceptances.  Plus you'll be learning more as you think about / search for answers, and from reading other people's answers.

Comment: @The Sasquatch I can fully relate, I'm in the same boat as you - not much expertise for most questions. But keep answering, sometimes you can get upvotes even if an answer has already been accepted - and asker can even change his 'answer' vote to yours (I've seen this happen). Remember, there's always StackOverflow and ServerFault and Area51 as well if SuperUser doesn't quite float your boat. : )